# How to get the top three from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the top 3 most sold products printed in a table. So I made the table that

```
select articel_id, article_count
from
(select articel_id, count( articel_id) as article_count
from sales_records_row
group by  articel_id
order by count(articel_id) DESC 
) as overview
```

Which gives

```
article_id      article_count
 1                30
 2                12
 4                8
 5                8
 8                8
 etc              etc
```

But I don't seem to be able to make calls on my new "overview table" since it is not a part of the original database. I would like to use the article_id to find the article name and then get a table with the columns

```
article_name      article_count
```

Can I even use my first code or is there a more suitable way to approach this?

**EDIT 
I have now come up with this solution. What is the difference between this and to have a JOIN?

```
select articles.name as 'Product Name', article_count
from
(select articel_id, count( articel_id) as article_count
from sales_records_row
group by  articel_id
order by count(articel_id) DESC limit 3
) as overview, articles
where articles.articel_id = overview.articel_id
```

Comment: Is `article_name` a column on `sales_record_row`?

Comment: What if there are ties?

Comment: No article_name is just in the the "articles"-table. Sorry for being unclear. I want to get by using the "article_id" as a foreign key. And if possible print all tied products

Answer (score 2):

If you want exactly three products (regardless of ties), then use `limit`:

```
select articel_id, count( articel_id) as article_count
from sales_records_row
group by  articel_id
order by count(articel_id) DESC 
limit 3;
```

If you want to store the results in a table, then use either:

```
create table <table name> as
```

or

```
create temporary table <table name> as
```

before the `select`.  Either will save the table so you can query it later.  The second creates a temporary table that will disappear when the session ends.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `JOINS`:

```
select o.articel_id, t.article_name, o.article_count  
from table t
inner join (select articel_id, count(articel_id) as article_count
            from sales_records_row
            group by  articel_id
            order by count(articel_id) DESC
            LIMIT 3) o on o.articel_id = t.articel_id;
```

Comment: I think this is quite it. But have two questions. 
Is the "o.articel_id" refering to the created "overview" table? And what do you mean by "from table t". What "t" is this?

Comment: @Marv. . . Yes you just need to rename `table` to `your table name`.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between JOIN and the update I've made in my question?

Comment: @Marv. . . Technically there is no difference. But your has older style of `JOIN` while i have suggested `Standard EXPLICIT JOIN` Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT articel_id, article_count, row_num
FROM(
   SELECT articel_id, count(articel_id) as article_count, @r:=@r+1 row_num
   FROM sales_records_row, (SELECT @r:=0) t
   GROUP BY articel_id ORDER BY article_count DESC
) a WHERE a.row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
```

Kindly try this

Comment: What advantage does the `row_num` operation give over a simple `LIMIT`?

Comment: Well, not much of a difference, however, it makes it a bit more dynamic in terms of selecting as column value and help show the sorting order.